# how to time-index the bag files?

Tags: ros, rosbag, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to know how to time-index the bag files. I think filenames can be time-stamp with actual ROS real-time. Im I wright?? Any help on this??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44779/how-to-time-index-the-bag-files?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, [rosbag record](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#record) will name its output file using the current system date and time. You can use the `-o` option to specify a prefix to go with that date stamp.

Most individual messages contain a ROS time stamp in the `Header` field.

Is that what you want?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-15**:
Ok. Thanks